# useing requirements_file flag do not start worker process in python dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to use external library (eg mecab-python) in gcp-dataflow.
In general, when using external libraries, use requestments.txt.
However, even though I have prepared requirements.txt, the worker process in dataflow does not work well.

I'm currently write code like that.

```
python3 -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --region $REGION \
  --output gs://$BUCKET/results/outputs \
  --runner  DataflowRunner \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --temp_location gs://$BUCKET/tmp/ \
  --requirements_file  ./requirements.txt
```

The worker process does not proceed after the following statement.

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:02:51.397Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DEBUG: Value "GroupAndSum/GroupByKey/Session" materialized.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:02:51.418Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DEBUG: Value "Write/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Session" materialized.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:02:51.429Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Executing operation Read/Read+Split+PairWIthOne+GroupAndSum/GroupByKey+GroupAndSum/Combine/Partial+GroupAndSum/GroupByKey/Reify+G
roupAndSum/GroupByKey/Write
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:Job 2021-01-17_05_02_36-17241324845585998354 is in state JOB_STATE_RUNNING
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:03:17.082Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 1 based on the rate of progress in the currently running stage(s).
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:03:46.622Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:03:46.632Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
```

but removeing   `--requirements_file  ./requirements.txt` flag the worker process proceeds normally.
log like that.

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:Job 2021-01-17_05_25_22-15232043370416313688 is in state JOB_STATE_RUNNING
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:25:58.407Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 1 based on the rate of progress in the currently running stage(s).
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:26:29.645Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:26:29.666Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:43.364Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Finished operation Read/Read+Split+PairWIthOne+GroupAndSum/GroupByKey+GroupAndSum/Combine/Partial+GroupAndSum/GroupByKey/Reify+Gr
oupAndSum/GroupByKey/Write <<Proceed to this stage.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:43.390Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Executing operation GroupAndSum/GroupByKey/Close
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:43.416Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Finished operation GroupAndSum/GroupByKey/Close
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:51.145Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Finished operation Write/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/Read+Write/Write/WriteImpl/InitializeWrite
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:51.167Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DEBUG: Value "Write/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/Read.out" materialized.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-17T13:28:51.177Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DEBUG: Value "Write/Write/WriteImpl/InitializeWrite.out" materialized.
```

version: `apache_beam-2.27.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

`requirements.txt` have simply one package.

```
python-dotenv
```

## Self-solved

Finally, I was able to run it by writing it in `setup.py` instead of using `requirements.txt`.

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='foobar test',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=[
        'python-dotenv==0.15.0',
    ],
    description='foobazz description',
)
```

then run those script.

```
#run.sh
python3 -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --region $REGION \
  --output gs://$BUCKET/results/outputs \
  --runner  DataflowRunner \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --temp_location gs://$BUCKET/tmp/ \
   --setup_file ./setup.py
```

Comment: Open up the worker logs in cloud logging (click the little box with the arrow in it in the top-right corner of the worker logs panel), that will show you detailed logs of why the installation failed.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at that log, but coundn't find any information that would help me solve the problem.Finally, I was able to run it by writing it in setup.py.